# Using pandas library to fill a blank value based on another columns value in a csv

Tags: pandas

I am new to pandas and I am having an issue. I am using the read CSV function to bring in a csv file. There are two columns in this file I need to look at. Here is some example data:

```
COUNTRY |  AREA
blank     Florida
blank     Florida
blank     Florida
Uk        London
UK        Westriver
```

I need to set the missing value "blank" to 'USA' where the area is equal to Florida. In this file, every value for the country is blank when the area is florida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If df is the name of your dataframe, do `df['COUNTRY'][df['AREA']=='Florida'] = 'USA'`